# owasp automated code review tools

Tags: java, security, sql-injection, owasp, code-access-security

We have developed a lot of code and unfortunately some of it may not be compliant and could have security flaws in accordance with the OWASP top ten. Does anyone have any guidance on automated code review tools which will check specifically for the OWASP breaches such as sql injection, javascript injection.

I dont want to crawl through lots of lines of code looking for the breaches but would muuch rather let some automated tool do it.

Thanks

Comment: I know that Sonar has some support for OWASP's top ten.  But even they [state here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Security-related+rules) that static code analysis isn't the best fit for testing security rules - there's little context for the rule to act on.

Comment: Thanks for that. Anyone else have any other tools they are aware of

Comment: You can try [Fortify](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/static-code-analysis-sast/). It's a commercial tool from HP, and so far it's the best one I've seen... but it might be expensive. This tool is like Sonar, but 100% dedicated to security.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and have a look at my friend's website that compares a lot of scanning tools, a lot of them are free.
These are not necessarily code scanning tools but running application scanning tools, but nonetheless it could be helpful to you:
http://www.sectoolmarket.com/